# How to use expect in text with line breaks?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm doing some automated tests with `capybara`, `cucumber` and `webdriver`.

And I have an objective to know if a text was loaded on a page, however there is a css property in it `white-space` that breaks the text and the expect cannot find.

My code is like this.

HTML

```
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
    Some 
    cool 
    text
</p>
```

Cucumber.Feature

```
expect(page).to have_selector('p', text: 'Some')
expect(page).to have_selector('p', text: 'cool')
expect(page).to have_selector('p', text: 'text')
```

I'm looking for something similar to:

```
#This text will failure in teste
expect(page).to have_selector('p', text: 'Some cool text')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara tries to treat text the way the browser displays it.  If the browser is displaying the text on multiple lines then try

```
expect(page).to have_selector('p', text: "Some\ncool\ntext")
```

If that doesn't work you can always use a regex along the lines of

```
expect(page).to have_selector('p', text: /Some\s+cool\s+text/)
```

Comment: The first method I've been trying to use for days, it still doesn't work, however the second method worked well, thank you very much.

Comment: @WEBLastWolf IF you can find the element call element.text on it -- it'll show you what the browser is telling Capybara the text is.  In fact you could just do `find('p', text: /Some\s+cool\s+text/).text` and see what it is